# Add a Varchar Value column that will contain specific characters along with the auto Increment ID. Using Code first, EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, model, code-first

I am developing an App using MVC5 and using Entity Framework Code first Approach for development. I have an ID column in Employee.cs Model class which auto increments as the Record is Inserted. I want to know How can I add another Column in my table with varchar type which will Look something Like this. **EMP233** where 233 i an ID Generated by Identiy Column.

**Note:**

I know how to do this task using SQL Server but I am curious to Know How it Can be done using EF Code first Approach.

Many people will Suggest me to get the latest max ID from db, Increment it and add it to the object something Like

```
int EmpMaxID = db.Employees.OrderByDescending(u => u.ID).FirstOrDefault();
employee.VarcharID = "EMP" + EmpMaxID;
```

This Approach is not the Best because lets suppose if the user add a record and system generates its ID as **234** and Moment after he deletes it. Then next time  in this case system will return Max ID as **233** i.e. *EmpMaxID = 233*   but the ID Generated by System is going to be **235**. So what we will get in return is a Record with ID = 235 AND EmpID = "EMP233" Which is wrong. I hope you got my Point.

Here is what I have tried but It didn't Work. IN THE MODELS I wrote something like this

```
public int ID { get; set; } // Unique numeric ID for each Employee

public string strEmpID // A varchar ID
    {
        get { return strEmpID}
        set { strEmpID= "EMP" + ID; } // ID is Auto Generated
    }
```

This Doesn't Work. Please help me completing this Task. Thanks

Comment: *I know how to do this task using SQL Server* And that's exactly where to do it. Why use an inferior method?

Comment: @GertArnold You are Right but the key is I want my Application to be completely independent on database i.e. when I run the Application on other  machine I want the EF To generate the database and all its Tables, Relationships (PK, FK), etc. Now tell me How can I make this logic in MVC Project. Should I write some thing in override OnModelBuild Method ? Here is the Query I would run in SQL Server for the intended purpose 

    `CREATE TABLE EmployeeMaster(
    [ID] int IDENTITY(1,1) Primary Key,
    [EmployeeNo]  AS ('EMP'+ RIGHT('0000000' + CAST(Id AS       VARCHAR(7)), 7)) PERSISTED
)`

Comment: Well, add it to the `Up` method of your migration code.

Answer (score 1):

When you save this record **for the first time**, get the Id, update the strEmpID property as well.

```
var emp = new Employee { Name="Scott" };
db.Employees.Add(emp);
db.SaveChanges();    

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(emp.strEmpID))
{
    e.strEmpID = "EMP" + e.Id;
    db.Entry(e).State=EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only safe way is to add the record and then get the id and update the record.

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
  context.MyEntities.AddObject(newEmployee);
  context.SaveChanges();

  int id = newEmployee.Id; // Your Identity column ID
  newEmployee.streEmpId = "EMP" + id;
  context.Entry(newEmployee).State = EntityState.Modified;
  context.SaveChanges();

}
```